# How to fill the blank space between the bars with specific color in gantt chart of highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

Current: [image: Current chart]

Expected One:
[image: expected one]

is there any way to fill that gap with a specific color in highcharts, i'm using chart type xrange here
thanks in advance code link in the comment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F4e2Y/185/ here the sample code  @ewolden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use yAxis `plotBands`:

```
    plotBands: [{
        from: -0.045,
        to: 0.04,
        color: 'red'
    }]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z10pjmcr/